# GCS credentials refresh for storage object

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, credentials

I have a service in Google Cloud Compute that is part of a multi-tenant application. We use vault to refresh credentials every 4-5 hours through a transient account in this location: `/dev/shm/gcp_credentials.json`.

**When creating a GCS storage object, I want to figure out what's the best way to update those credentials.**

I noticed there's a method to build the storage object that allows me to pass a credentials object. I'm using `google-auth-credentials-library:0.16.2`The credentials object has a method `credentials.refresh()` as per the doc reference: https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-credentials/0.16.2/com/google/auth/Credentials.html and for the storage object, I'm using `google-cloud-storage:1.83.0`

```
Storage refreshStorage() {
    return StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials)
        .setProjectId("project_id").build().getService();
}
```

What I want to understand is, if I call `credentials.refresh()`, will this guarantee that when I call `storage.create(blobInfo, records);` it re-authenticates, or do I have to call again the above method to pass a new storage object with credentials refreshed?

Comment: Your questions is really unclear to me. First, " I don't fully understand the flow when a private Storage storage; object" what does this mean? Second, where are you running this code, in App Engine, in Cloud Functions, K8, outside of GCP? It would be awesome if you also include some links to the libraries that you are using because I’m not sure where are you getting the `credentials.refresh()` and some context on what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @Chris32  thanks for  the reply  I updated the original  message.  Let me  know if  that makes sense

Comment: You are correct, the `credentials.refresh()` will remove the cached state of your credentials so the proper process will be refreshing your credentials > calling `credentials.refresh()` to avoid any error reading the cache credential > working with your storage.

Answer (score 1):

The `credentials.refresh()` will remove the cached state of your credentials so the proper process will be:

> refreshing your credentials > calling credentials.refresh() to avoid
>   any error reading the cache credential > working with your storage